# como buscar primer nombre o segundo y apellidos

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

necesito su ayuda tengo la siguiente consulta

```
$texto = mb_strtoupper ($texto);
    $query = "Select id_cliente, nombre +' '+ ap_paterno +' '+ ap_materno as cliente From clientes where eliminado = 0 AND (";
    $query .= "nombre LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_paterno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_materno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_paterno +' '+ ap_materno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_materno +' '+ ap_paterno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR nombre +' '+ ap_paterno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR nombre +' '+ ap_materno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR nombre +' '+ ap_materno +' '+ ap_paterno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR nombre +' '+ ap_paterno +' '+ ap_materno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_paterno +' '+ nombre +' '+ ap_materno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_materno +' '+ nombre +' '+ ap_paterno LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_paterno +' '+ ap_materno +' '+ nombre LIKE '%" . $texto . "%'";
    $query .= "OR ap_materno +' '+ ap_paterno +' '+ nombre LIKE '%" . $texto . "%')";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    return $result;
```

pero necesito poder buscar al **cliente** por su segundo nombre también contenido en el campo **nombre**
por ejemplo si tengo:
***miguel angel nuñez nolasco*** y busco ***angel nuñez nolasco*** si me regresa el cliente pero si lo busco como ***miguel nuñez nolasco***, no me retorna nada :=(
¿Alguna Sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías [concatenar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) nombre(s) y apellidos, separar los datos en palabras y *buscarlas todas* en el nombre resultante, no en campos separados:

```
// Separar palabras
$palabras = explode(' ', mb_strtoupper ($texto));
$query = "Select id_cliente, CONCAT(nombre, ' ', ap_paterno, ' ', ap_materno) as cliente FROM clientes WHERE eliminado = 0";
// Recorrer arreglo para agregar cada palabra
foreach($palabras as $index => $palabra) {
    // Solo la primer palabra lleva HAVING, el resto AND
    $separador = ($index == 0) ? 'HAVING' : 'AND';
    $query .= " $separador cliente LIKE '%$palabra%'";
}
$result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
return $result;
```

Si el nombre del cliente es `miguel angel nuñez nolasco` las siguientes búsquedas lo van a encontrar:

```
- angel
- miguel nolasco
- nuñez nolasco angel
- angel nolasco miguel nuñez
```

Es decir, no importa el orden, solo que todas las palabras buscadas formen parte del nombre.

Comment: me retorna "el nombre de la columna 'cliente' no es válido" no puedo usar la funcion CONCAT por que uso sql server 2008 r2 :'c

Comment: Sí, error mío, los alias generados por `CONCAT()` no pueden compararse directamente en `WHERE` y, en su lugar, se debe usar `HAVING`. Edité la respuesta.

Comment: listo, muchísimas gracias, eres un crack :D